# How to use a custom name for app.config or hard-code config values in my assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com, interop

I have written a class library in C# (mydll.dll) which accesses a third party dll (3rdpdll.dll). Mydll.dll, in turn gets consumed via COM interop by a non-.NET process (myapp.exe).

Mydll.dll is .NET 4.0 but 3rdpdll.dll has been built using v2.0.50727, so when I run myapp.exe, I get the following error:

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the
>   runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information...

This gets fixed if I create a file called "myapp.exe.config" next to myapp.exe containing the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Problem is myapp.exe gets updated a lot and contains version information in the name, such as myapp.v2.063.exe. This would require the config file to be renamed with every new iteration of the app (myapp.v2.063.exe.config
).

Is there a way for me to declare a static name for the config file, such as "app.config" so that it does not need to be renamed and reshipped along with every new iteration of myapp.exe? Or better yet, could I hard-code the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy attribute in mydll.dll so that I can avoid using a config file altogether?

Comment: Why must you contain the version in the file name?

Comment: That's the policy of the client.

Comment: If MyApp.exe gets updated a lot, could you prevail on it to rename or even autogenerate the config file with a matching name before its first call into any .NET code?

Comment: Seems like an extreme work-around, but that *would* solve all my problems. It's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13087/joe)'s idea:

> If MyApp.exe gets updated a lot, could you prevail on it to rename or
>   even autogenerate the config file with a matching name before its
>   first call into any .NET code? – [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13087/joe) Jan 12 at 17:38

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010 you can rename the app.config file with:

in **Project** -> **Project Properties**, select **Build Events** tab and edit the post-build event command-line to rename the .config file, example:

```
rename "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" "$(TargetFileName).versionX"
```

Comment: That doesn't really help me. Myapp.exe is not .NET, it does not get built in Visual Studio. It's build process has no connection to that of mydll.dll. Also I do not want to have to ship a new app.config file with each new iteration of the app seeing as it only refers to mydll.dll which will not be updated as often.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but just thinking, if you recompile your .net 4.0 assembly in .net 2.0 framework, as .backward compatibility is there. Then i am thinking this error of mixedmode assembly should go and you may not need this config.

Comment: This, I think, is a good idea, but I have already tried it and it doesn't seem to work. After switching my project to 2.0, when I add 3rdpdll.dll to my references I get the following error: "3rdpdll.dll or one or it's dependencies requires a later version of the .NET Framework that the one specified in the project.". Not sure why. If I switch to 3.0 I don't have this problem, but I do get "That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers." when launching myapp.exe. This would again require an app.config setting to solve.